# I was able to re-introduce the process that had not been done anymore. Past perfect?

Tags: meaning, past-tense, translation, perfect-aspect

I am not sure whether or not there should be past simple or past perfect:

> I was able to re-introduce the procedure that had not been being
>   followed anymore.
>
> I was able to re-introduce the procedure that was not being followed
>   anymore.

I think that because the process has not been followed (and was not before the re-introduction), this should be implied by the past perfect.

Comment: _Procedures_ are followed and _processes_ are carried out.

Comment: The second variant uses the correct tenses, but I'd prefer 'I was able to re-introduce the procedure that was no longer being followed.' There also needs to have been a previous reference to this procedure (or the 'the' is wrong), and _that_ was probably the place to mention that it had been abandoned.

Comment: THank you. Why the first is not correct? If it was beig followed in the past and stopped? I mean, there was a duration of following the procedures beforhe the point where I re-introduced that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple reason why your second example is not correct: **English does not use the perfect tense forms of the progressive aspect of the passive voice.**

We just do not say ‘has/had been being done’.

You can say ‘has/had been done’ (perfect passive) or ‘is/was being done’ (progressive passive), but not ‘has/had been being done’ (perfect progressive passive). You choose *either* perfect tense *or* progressive aspect in the passive, but not both at once.

Therefore, in your case, you can choose either the perfect passive:

> Procedure that had no longer been followed

– or the progressive passive:

> Procedure that was no longer being followed

In this case, the progressive aspect of the non-following is more important than the perfective aspect, therefore the progressive form ‘wins’ and is more natural-sounding.

Your way of considering the perfect construction and its semantic meaning is correct, and if the verb had been in the active mood, the past perfect progressive would indeed have been the proper form to use:

> I was able to reintroduce the procedure, which *we had no longer been following* (up to that point).

Comment: You are wrong. "A book had been being written." - Oxford dictionary. They do say it is rare, but it definitely exists...

Comment: Sure English HAS past perfect progressive passive. I recommend the that the author read about the grammar here: http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/the-past-perfect-progressive-passive-of-english-verbs/

Comment: It is possible to create, of course. But it is so rare that it is, to me at least, ungrammatical. Similarly, the future past perfect passive is entirely ungrammatical to me, even though it is a possible construction and a logical argument can easily be made for its use (‘will have had been being done’). For all practical purposes, these forms are not used in English. I have edited the answer to specify that the construction _isn’t_ used, rather than that it is impossible.

Comment: But the English does use it. Maybe Americans (who often barely use future perfect) do not, but it not that rare, especially in written form.

Comment: I agree with @JanusBahsJacquet. "had not been being followed" is very awkward sounding to my American Midwest ear. In our region you would say "had not been followed."

Comment: Amazingly, if I search Google books in the 19th century for "have been being" and "had been being", followed by a verb, these phrases only appear in grammar books. That is, the progressive perfect passive constructions were deemed to be grammatical by grammarians, but *nobody every used them.* They do start appearing in books in the late 20th century, but are quite rare.

Comment: To be fair to the 19th century grammarians, I've looked more closely at their grammar books and some of these books argue that, despite their acceptance by other grammarians, these forms do not actually exist.

Comment: @PeterShor, thank you for taking the time to look through that and finding some confirmation that this form _is_ in fact all but unused. SilkySand, the English do not use it either. I don’t know if perhaps speakers of Indian English might use it, but it is not used naturally by native speakers of either American, British, or Irish English, and I’m almost 100% certain not by those of Australian English, either.

Comment: But what about the dominatrix who said to the masochist, as she pats her palm with a riding crop, "You have been being a very bad boy, now haven't you"? Someone needs to have a word with her.

Comment: @rhetorician, not at all. That’s an _active_ construction, in which the perfect progressive is perfectly common. If said masochist later on described her attitude saying, “My dominatrix had been being enraged by my disobedience”, though, someone would need to have a word with _him_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I'll certainly make a note of that! I'll also let her know she's off the hook, grammatically speaking, that is.